# CodeIgniter 404 error page not found in pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, http-status-code-404

I have problem making CodeIgniter pagination when i click on link i get 404 page not found
my code in controler is

```
class Records extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url']= 'localhost/records';
        $config['total_rows']= $this->db->get('pages')->num_rows;
        $config['per_page']= 2;
        $config['num_links']= 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['query'] = $this->db->get('pages',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(2));



        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('includes/nav_home');
        $this->load->view('view_list', $data);
        $this->load->view('view_footer');
```

}

i tried diffrent uri segments, but still no result. ? I am writing code in right way. my base_url is empty in config file?

in view my code is

```
<?php
echo $this->session->flashdata('item');
echo '<h4>Lista podataka</h4>';

foreach ($query->result() as $q):

?>
<a href="/z/update/grab/<?php echo $q->id;?>/<?php echo $q->info; ?>"><?php echo $q->info . br() . br()?></a>
<?php 
endforeach;

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understand you can't access your next page pagination? So I think it's because of this `$config['base_url']= 'localhost/records';`

you should put your complete url(including the controller name and function name), so it should be

`$config['base_url']= 'localhost/records/index.php/controller_name/function';`

and in your uri segment should `$this->uri->segment(3)`

Comment: its problem because i put pagination in index() function, i created separate function, and it works!

Comment: No. You should put correct base_url, try to change your code in this and tell me if you still have error(s)

Comment: i did this and its working function page()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/z/records/page';
        $config['total_rows']= $this->db->get('pages')->num_rows;
        $config['per_page']= 2;
        $config['num_links']= 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        
        $this->load->model('Data');
        $data['query'] = $this->Data->data_pagination($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
       
       
    }

Comment: do you have no other problem? vote me up and mark as solve if this is helpful

Comment: thanks, could you helpe more, i am currently learning in one company, maybe they will hire me if i show some skills, i learned php all on my own from books

Comment: could u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788447/codeigniter-dry-navigation

Answer (score 0):

try may be change uri segment

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url']= base_url().'/records/index'; 
    $config['total_rows']= $this->db->get('pages')->num_rows;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['per_page']= 2;
    $config['num_links']= 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get('pages',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
```

For more follow :- [pagination in codeigniter](http://www.weblint4u.com/how-to-create-pagination-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: its problem because i put pagination in index() function, i created separate function, and it works!

Comment: not a function issue you need to use correct base url

Comment: yes maybe i should put index infront! thats error probably

Answer (score 0):

Base Url needs to be

```
$config['base_url']= 'records/index';
```

Answer (score 0):

Base url in must be contain the same function that is used to fetch data
 it means $config['base_url']='localhost/project/records/index';