# CodeIgniter Dry Navigation

Tags: codeigniter, controller, navigation, dry, extends

My boss told me make dry navigation dont use repetitive code, for navigation i am trying to extend CI_Controler and with construct load header nav, body, footer files.

My question is when i create new controller and when i try to load different view files, how to achive that???

my extended controler

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('view_header');
        $this->load->view('includes/nav_home');
        $this->load->view('view_home');
        $this->load->view('view_footer');   

    }
}
```

and later when i am creating new controler how to load diffrent view files

```
class Pages extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {


        $this->load->view('includes/nav_new_view');
        $   

    }
}
```

Comment: What is "dry navigation"?

Comment: what do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template library yourself. For example :

```
function template($view_name,$view_data){
    //below will return html string from view name
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view($view_name,$view_data,true)

    //load main template view and pass the html string to main template
    $this->load->view('main_template',$data);
}
```

In main template, just echo $content

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're trying to achieve a template situation. For this, the best way is to actually call your templates view files within a primary page view. What I mean is your controller function (not the constructor, an actual class function representing a page) should call a primary view such as

```
$this->load->view('page1', $this->data);
```

and within that file, you call

```
$this->load->view('nav', $this->data);
```

then your content and then

```
$this->load->view('footer', $this->data);
```

You would then repeat the process for page 2 where in your controller's page2 function, you would call

```
$this->load->view('page2', $this->data);
```

and your page2 view file is almost identical to page1 except you use your page 2 content in that area.

You could even use a single template view file and pass it a `$content` variable (which obviously changes per page) and call

```
$this->load->view('template', $this->data);
```